# Excel Copy Row to Another Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

[Image of row I'm trying to copy to workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez3Xb.png)

I have the following row that I want to copy into another excel workbook. Here is the code I have so far. I'm not sure how to copy the row into the workbook that I create and open later on. It copies the rows that have the name associated with the input variable value, but not the row that has the value, "PROGRAM" in it. I don't understand why.

```
Sub ProgramExport()

  Dim Program As Range
  Set Program = Range("C1:C2000")
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim wbThis As Workbook
  Dim newBook As Workbook
  Dim value As String
  Dim userID As String
  Dim fn As String
  Dim x As String

  Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

  value = InputBox("Please enter the program you'd like to export.")
  userID = InputBox("Please enter your user id.")
  fn = "C:\Users\" & userID & "\Desktop\" & value & ".xlsx"
  'aFN = "C:\Users\ashaikh5\Desktop\Copy of TS L2L3v11.xlsm"
  newBook.SaveAs (fn)

  x = "PROGRAM"

  For Each cell In Program

      If cell = value Or cell = x Then
          If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = cell.EntireRow
          Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, cell.EntireRow)
          End If
      Else
          'cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3

  End If

  Next
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
  rng.Select
  Selection.Copy
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=fn
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
  erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
  ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  ActiveSheet.Columns("A:L").ColumnWidth = 14
  ActiveSheet.Columns("C").AutoFit
  ActiveSheet.Columns("N:CM").ColumnWidth = 14
  ActiveWorkbook.Save
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you checked there are no trailing spaces? Btw you need to read up on how to avoid Select and use workbook/worksheet variables.

Comment: I'm a total beginner in VBA, this is something I've made just from the little tidbits I have learned through google. I'll read up in the variables though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub ProgramExport()

  Dim Program As Range
  Set Program = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C1:C2000")
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim newBook As Workbook
  Dim value As String
  Dim userID As String
  Dim fn As String
  Dim x As String

  Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

  value = InputBox("Please enter the program you'd like to export.")
  userID = InputBox("Please enter your user id.")
  fn = "C:\Users\" & userID & "\Desktop\" & value & ".xlsx"
  'aFN = "C:\Users\ashaikh5\Desktop\Copy of TS L2L3v11.xlsm"
  newBook.SaveAs (fn)

  x = "PROGRAM"

  For Each cell In Program

      If cell = value Or cell = x Then
          If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = cell.EntireRow
          Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, cell.EntireRow)
          End If
      Else
          'cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3

  End If

  Next
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = newBook.Worksheets(1)
  erow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
  rng.Copy
  ws.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial
  ws.Columns("A:L").ColumnWidth = 14
  ws.Columns("C").AutoFit
  ws.Columns("N:CM").ColumnWidth = 14
  newBook.Save
  newBook.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Right, so this solves using worksheet/workbook variables. The first row still doesn't copy. Is there a way I can just copy the second row from the first workbook and paste it in the second workbook that is opened? After the initial copying is done.

Comment: Do you want to copy the header or what?

Comment: Yeah, so I want to copy row #2 from the initial workbook and paste it into the new workbook that was created.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Thank you!

```
Sub ProgramExport()

  Dim Program As Range
  Set Program = Range("C1:C2000")
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim wbThis As Workbook
  Dim newBook As Workbook
  Dim value As String
  Dim userID As String
  Dim fn As String
  Dim x As String

  Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

  value = InputBox("Please enter the program you'd like to export.")
  userID = InputBox("Please enter your user id.")
  fn = "C:\Users\" & userID & "\Desktop\" & value & ".xlsx"
  'aFN = "C:\Users\ashaikh5\Desktop\Copy of TS L2L3v11.xlsm"
  newBook.SaveAs (fn)

  x = "PROGRAM"

  For Each cell In Program

      If cell = value Or cell.value = x Then
          If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = cell.EntireRow
          Else
            Set rng = Union(rng, cell.EntireRow)
          End If
      Else
          'cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3

  End If

  Next
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = newBook.Worksheets(1)
  erow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
  rng.Copy
  ws.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial
  ws.Columns("A:L").ColumnWidth = 14
  ws.Columns("C").AutoFit
  ws.Columns("N:CM").ColumnWidth = 14
  newBook.Save
  Set wbThis = Workbooks("TS L2L3v11.xlsm")
  'wbThis.Activate
  Dim test As Worksheet: Set test = wbThis.Worksheets(5)
  test.Rows(2).Copy
  ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
  newBook.Close


End Sub
```